# VS IDE: Split the tabs Horizontally or Vertically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

in VS IDE, when more than one tab is open, we can split them horizontally or vertically. BUT they should be different files in each tab. Is there a way I can have the SAME file in BOTH tabs? because when I am working on one method that is calling other methods in the same file, I want to easily see them instead of having to scrolling up and down...
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Click Window, New Window to open a second window for the current file.

You can then drag the new window to a different tab group.